# 30% pizza to 10% people, 70% pizza to 90% people, what is the difference?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, percentages

Yesterday I was reading an article, which had a statistic exposing a certain disproportion in different groups of people. I will now reformulate this problem in a more "neutral" way.

If 10% of people get 30% of pizza, then how many times more pizza does an average person in the 10% group get than the average person in the 90% group?

I know we can solve this problem the following way:

> EDIT: $$x/(x+1) = .3$$
>   so $x=0.428571$, which means that the 10% group gets $x=0.428571$ pizzas every time the other group gets one pizza.

But how can we solve this in a different way? I seem to have always had some issue with percentages, despite doing well in much more complicated math or physics problems. Here's what I've tried:

$30/10 = 70x/90$, so $x\approx 3.8571$, which is obviously false, and we can easily verify this.

Can someone please clarify why exactly my second equation is incorrect, and what a correct equation should look like? I mean an equation with proportions, but not like the first equation, which is easy to come up with, but I want a more "direct" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get seems correct to me. I don't know where did $x/(x+1)=.7$ come from? Anyway, you get think in two (seemingly) different ways.

The first one is a straightforward calculation: let $P$ be total number of pizzas and $n$ total number of people. $0.3P$ goes to $0.1n$, while $0.7P$ goes to $0.9n$. A person from the first group gets $\frac{0.3P}{0.1n} = 3P/n$ pizzas, while from the second group a person gets $\frac{0.7P}{0.9n} = 7/9\,P/n$ pizzas, so 10-percenters get $3/(7/9) = 27/7$ times more.

The second way is to denote with $x$ and $y$ the number of pizzas a person from the first or second group gets. Obviously, number of pizzas any person gets is directly proportional to what the total number of pizzas is, while it is inversely proportional to the total number of people, so we can write:

$$\left.\begin{align}
x:y &= 0.3:0.7\\
&= \frac 1{0.1}:\frac 1{0.9}
\end{align}\right\}\implies x:y = \frac{0.3}{0.1}:\frac{0.7}{0.9} = 3:\frac 79 = 27:7$$

Comment: My mistake with the first one (correcting it now). The first equation comes  from the fact that if the 90% group gets 1 pizza then the other group gets x pizzas. So the relation must satisfy $x/(1+x)=.3$, indicating that every time someone in the 90% group gets 1 pizza, someone in the other group gets $x$ pizzas, and so (pizzas received in the 10% group)/(total pizzas received) = 30%.

Comment: Addition to my first equation: then we get $(0.428571 / (.1 )) / (1/.9) = 3.857139...$, the same answer actually... But why doesn't it work when we verify it?

Comment: Oh, I see... $(3.857139 * .1)/(3.857139*0.1  + 1*0.9 )$, that's how we verify it... I wasn't careful enough.

Answer (score 1):

The proportion you need is $(30/10) = (1+x) (70/90)$ where $x$ is the additional "slice" of pizza-for-the-rich on top of the portion of pizza-for-the-poor.

Comment: Are you sure that this gives "*how many times more* pizza does an average person in the 10% group get than the average person in the 90% group?" (emphasis mine) compared to "how much more"?

Comment: Then $x=2.86$, and we can verify that this is not the case.

Comment: Apologies for my insufficient command of English. What I am trying to say is that $x$ above works as the "rate of interest" and tells you that the rich is eating 285.7% more than the poor.

Comment: Please see my comments under Ennar's answer.